# How do I conditional format entire row based on a single cell using google Sheets python API script?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, conditional-statements, row, google-sheets-api

I am able to use the Google Sheets API (python) to conditionally format (change the cell color of) a single cell based on a user input value but not the entire row.  Is there any way to do this?  Here's the code I'm using that works for a single cell (just the cell that's being changed).

```
"addConditionalFormatRule": {
        "rule": {
          "ranges": [
            {
              "sheetId": tabidnumber,
              "startRowIndex": 1,
              "endRowIndex": row_count  

            }
          ],
          "booleanRule": {
            "condition": {
              "type": "TEXT_EQ",
              "values": [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": "WAITING"
                }
              ]
            },
            "format": {
                "backgroundColor": {
                "green": 0.5,
                "red": 0.5,
              }},

            }

        },
        "index": 1
      }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update single row formatting for entire sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047974/update-single-row-formatting-for-entire-sheet)

Answer (score 1):

For example, when `startRowIndex` is 1 and `endRowIndex` is not used, Sheets API uses the range as from row 2 to the end of row of Sheet. So please remove `endRowIndex` from `ranges` in your request body and try to run again. By this, this update is reflected to the entire row of the sheet.

#### Modified request body:

```
"addConditionalFormatRule": {
  "rule": {
    "ranges": [
      {
        "sheetId": tabidnumber,
        "startRowIndex": 1
      }
    ],
    "booleanRule": {
      "condition": {
        "type": "TEXT_EQ",
        "values": [
          {
            "userEnteredValue": "WAITING"
          }
        ]
      },
      "format": {
        "backgroundColor": {
          "green": 0.5,
          "red": 0.5
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "index": 1
}
```

#### Note:

- I had known this from my experience. Although I had looked for the reference documents related to this, I couldn't find it. I'm sorry.